# Book identification - yin-yang tattoo on arm

Tags: novel, young-adult, story-identification

It is a "people from normal world journey to fantasy world" plot. One of the protagonists, a young or teenage girl, has a yin-yang symbol on her arm. At one point in the book, one of the antagonists forces an underling to touch the tattoo. When the underling (an orc-like being) touches the "bad" colour, he feels pleasure. When he touches the "good" colour, he feels pain. When he touches both parts of the tattoo at once, he is destroyed.

I think there is a broken tower or lighthouse glass. The missing piece is why there is evil in the land. One of the protagonists (a young boy, if I remember right) climbs the tower and replaces the broken piece of glass, restoring goodness to the land.

It is entirely possible those two plot points are from two different books. It was a while ago (mid `80s). I have a vague idea it is a British YA or Children's book.

My Google-fu is weak. All I seem to be finding is The Crystal Shard and the Weirdstone of Brisingamen. I'm sure its not the first and I'm pretty sure it's not the second (I'm reading it at the moment).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this book well!!  It's very famous in New Zealand.  The title is:  *'The Halfmen of O'*, by Maurice Gee.  It won some book awards when it came out.  Fantastic YA book!  I must read it again.

Basic outline:  Susan Ferris and her cousin Nick (the protagonists) basically wander back and forth between our world (New Zealand specifically) and a fantasy world.  She has a yin-yang birthmark on her arm.   the halflings on the other side are basically either good or evil.  If an evil one touches the 'good' part of her birthmark, they writhe in pain, etc, etc.  She is somehow (I forget how) the savior of this other place.

I don't recall a glass tower or anything like that - but it has been a while since I read it.  There is also at least one sequel - *'The Priests of Ferris'*.  Possibly more sequels.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much.

Comment: _Priests of Ferris_ is second in the trilogy, the third and final is called _Motherstone_. [More info on Maurice Gee](http://www.bookcouncil.org.nz/writer/gee-maurice/)