# Story about a girl with a tattoo/symbol on her wrist that is deadly to enemies that touch it

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novel

I seem to remember reading this story in a compilation of short YA stories, but it could have been an excerpt from a novel (i.e. basically a promotion of other novels). I seem to remember there were illustrations alongside the story, but they could have been added as part of the compilation.
As it was a very long time ago that I read it, a lot of the details are fuzzy. Probably somewhere around 1997.

The story follows a young teenage girl who was either imprisoned from birth or had been captured early on in her life. She had a tattoo or birthmark on her wrist, possibly on the inside of her wrist, and I seem to remember it resembling a [triquetra.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triquetra) Her captors weren't unkind to her, mainly aloof, but they all avoided touching the tattoo. At some point during her imprisonment one of the guards inadvertently touched the symbol, at which point she heard a rushing of wind and the guard fell down dead.

Something happens within the story that forces her captors to move her, and they transport her to another location along a mountain path. Something else happens that causes her guards to move to a defensive stance (an attack by another group?), and one of the lead guards takes her hostage with his arm around her neck, possibly with a dagger held to her throat. She slowly moves her wrist and gently touches the symbol to his arm, at which point she hears a deafening sound of wind and the lead guard gets thrown back off the mountain, at which point the story ends.

Comment: Potential duplicate. Does this look familiar? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63640/book-identification-yin-yang-tattoo-on-arm?rq=1

Comment: Also an answer to this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236053/fantasy-book-about-good-and-evil-within-where-a-girl-is-kidnapped-by-a-gold-min?rq=1